# TestNG: testng doesn't support the "mode" attribute

Tags: java, testng

Здравствуйте. Не так давно, когда изучал TestNG, все работало. А теперь когда хочу применить на практике, выдает ошибку:
testng doesn't support the "mode" attribute
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим? (NetBeans)

Comment: добавьте в вопрос [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, разобрался.Добавлял к проекту testng.jar чего делать не надо. Достаточно просто создать тестовый класс средствами NetBeans.